# How to match two exact values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to fetch all documents that match exactly the given two terms, i.e., 
id=100 AND name=xyz

My query

```
query: {
    constant_score: {
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: [
             { term: { id: '100' } },
             { term: { name: 'xyz' } },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

But this gives all documents that either match id or name or both.
I want only those documents that matches both attributes and they should exactly match.

How should I do it?

I looked up here. [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

ES Version - 2.1.1

Comment: can you also post your mappings ans es version?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"id": "100"}},
                {"match": {"name": "XYZ"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives the same result as before. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"id": "100"}},
                {"match": {"name": "XYZ"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The above code should do the trick. If that is not working, there might be something wrong with your index_option or analyzer setting. Can you put your mapping?